# How to convert EUR to BTC on Binance via API call?

Tags: linux, curl, bitcoin, binance, binance-api-client

I would like to convert EUR to BTC via API call on Binance. The API key already created, but I don't know how to make an API call to do this. The official documentation doesn't have any example.

I would like to do this on Linux (with cURL).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [new order](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#new-order--trade) endpoint. Symbol is `BTCEUR`.

The documentation gives an [example](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#example-1-as-a-request-body) of signing the request using `openssl` and submitting it using `curl`.

```
[linux]$ echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
(stdin)= c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71
```

```
(HMAC SHA256)
[linux]$ curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A" -X POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order' -d 'symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71'
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems okay, but I'm confused with the "quantity" and the "price" parts. Do you have any idea what values are correct here? I would like to buy BTC for 50 EUR.

Comment: Quantity is the amount of BTC (base asset) that you want to buy. If you want to specify the EUR amount (quote asset) that you want to spend, you can use the `quoteOrderQty` property instead... Price is the price for which you want to submit the `LIMIT` type order (e.g. 30,000 eur), it will execute when the market price reaches this defined price. If you want to buy BTC for whatever is the current price, use the `MARKET` type.